# Не работает умный фильтр Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

День добрый подскажите, как можно решить данную проблемку, подключил с начала комплексный компонент каталог, потом умный фильтр. Зашёл в настройки инфоблока и поставил галочки показывать в умном фильтре, вид в умном фильтре, показывать развёрнутым и всё это напротив свойств цена и бренды. После чего появился фильтр с параметрами цена и бренды, но если нажать на кнопку показать ничего не выдаёт?

Код умного фильтра

```
 <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"bitrix:catalog.smart.filter",
".default",
Array(
    "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
    "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
    "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
    "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
    "DISPLAY_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "Y",
    "FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter",
    "FILTER_VIEW_MODE" => "vertical",
    "IBLOCK_ID" => "1",
    "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "Catalog",
    "INSTANT_RELOAD" => "N",
    "PAGER_PARAMS_NAME" => "arrPager",
    "POPUP_POSITION" => "left",
    "SAVE_IN_SESSION" => "N",
    "SECTION_CODE" => "",
    "SECTION_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
    "SECTION_ID" => $_REQUEST["SECTION_ID"],
    "SECTION_TITLE" => "-",
    "SEF_MODE" => "N",
    "TEMPLATE_THEME" => "blue",
    "XML_EXPORT" => "N"
)
```

);?>

Код каталога

```
             <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"bitrix:catalog",
"Catalog",
Array(
    "ACTION_VARIABLE" => "action",
    "ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN" => "N",
    "ADD_PICT_PROP" => "-",
    "ADD_PROPERTIES_TO_BASKET" => "Y",
    "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
    "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
    "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
    "BASKET_URL" => "/personal/basket.php",
    "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
    "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
    "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
    "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
    "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "Catalog",
    "DETAIL_ADD_DETAIL_TO_SLIDER" => "N",
    "DETAIL_BACKGROUND_IMAGE" => "-",
    "DETAIL_BRAND_USE" => "N",
    "DETAIL_BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
    "DETAIL_CHECK_SECTION_ID_VARIABLE" => "N",
    "DETAIL_DETAIL_PICTURE_MODE" => "IMG",
    "DETAIL_DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
    "DETAIL_DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT_MODE" => "E",
    "DETAIL_META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
    "DETAIL_META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
    "DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(0=>"",1=>"",),
    "DETAIL_SET_CANONICAL_URL" => "N",
    "DETAIL_USE_COMMENTS" => "N",
    "DETAIL_USE_VOTE_RATING" => "Y",
    "DETAIL_VOTE_DISPLAY_AS_RATING" => "rating",
    "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
    "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
    "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => "sort",
    "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD2" => "id",
    "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => "asc",
    "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc",
    "FILTER_VIEW_MODE" => "VERTICAL",
    "IBLOCK_ID" => "1",
    "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "Catalog",
    "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "N",
    "LABEL_PROP" => "-",
    "LINE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "3",
    "LINK_ELEMENTS_URL" => "link.php?PARENT_ELEMENT_ID=#ELEMENT_ID#",
    "LINK_IBLOCK_ID" => "",
    "LINK_IBLOCK_TYPE" => "",
    "LINK_PROPERTY_SID" => "",
    "LIST_BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
    "LIST_META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
    "LIST_META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
    "LIST_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(0=>"",1=>"",),
    "MESSAGE_404" => "",
    "MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET" => "В корзину",
    "MESS_BTN_BUY" => "Купить",
    "MESS_BTN_COMPARE" => "Сравнение",
    "MESS_BTN_DETAIL" => "Подробнее",
    "MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "Нет в наличии",
    "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
    "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
    "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
    "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
    "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
    "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
    "PAGER_TITLE" => "Товары",
    "PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "30",
    "PARTIAL_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => "N",
    "PRICE_CODE" => array(0=>"ATTR_PRICE",),
    "PRICE_VAT_INCLUDE" => "Y",
    "PRICE_VAT_SHOW_VALUE" => "N",
    "PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE" => "id",
    "PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => array(),
    "PRODUCT_PROPS_VARIABLE" => "prop",
    "PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE" => "",
    "SECTIONS_HIDE_SECTION_NAME" => "N",
    "SECTIONS_SHOW_PARENT_NAME" => "Y",
    "SECTIONS_VIEW_MODE" => "TILE",
    "SECTION_BACKGROUND_IMAGE" => "-",
    "SECTION_COUNT_ELEMENTS" => "N",
    "SECTION_ID_VARIABLE" => "SECTION_ID",
    "SECTION_TOP_DEPTH" => "2",
    "SEF_FOLDER" => "/catalog/",
    "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
    "SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array("sections"=>"","section"=>"#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/","element"=>"#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/#ELEMENT_ID#/","compare"=>"compare.php?action=#ACTION_CODE#","smart_filter"=>"#SECTION_ID#/filter/#SMART_FILTER_PATH#/apply/",),
    "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
    "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
    "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
    "SHOW_404" => "N",
    "SHOW_DEACTIVATED" => "N",
    "SHOW_PRICE_COUNT" => "1",
    "SHOW_TOP_ELEMENTS" => "N",
    "SIDEBAR_DETAIL_SHOW" => "Y",
    "SIDEBAR_PATH" => "",
    "SIDEBAR_SECTION_SHOW" => "Y",
    "TEMPLATE_THEME" => "blue",
    "TOP_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "9",
    "TOP_ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => "sort",
    "TOP_ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD2" => "id",
    "TOP_ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => "asc",
    "TOP_ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc",
    "TOP_LINE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "3",
    "TOP_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(0=>"",1=>"",),
    "TOP_VIEW_MODE" => "SECTION",
    "USE_COMPARE" => "N",
    "USE_ELEMENT_COUNTER" => "Y",
    "USE_FILTER" => "N",
    "USE_MAIN_ELEMENT_SECTION" => "N",
    "USE_PRICE_COUNT" => "N",
    "USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY" => "N",
    "USE_STORE" => "N",
    "VARIABLE_ALIASES" => array("compare"=>array("ACTION_CODE"=>"action",),)
)
```

);?>

Answer (score 2):

> подключил с начала комплексный компонент каталог, потом умный фильтр

1. Нужно чтобы фильтр отрабатывал раньше вызова компонента `bitrix:catalog.section`, который вызывается (должен вызываться) в вашем кастомизированном шаблоне `Catalog` для комплексного компонента `bitrix:catalog`. Порядок важен, т.к. в противном случае $GLOBALS["arrFilter"] будет пустой.
2. В комплексном компоненте `bitrix:catalog` уже есть фильтр (если вы его не выпилили в шаблоне), но он у вас отключен `"USE_FILTER" => "N"`. Лучше использовать именно его.
3. Если по верстке все же требуется вывести фильтр после списка товаров, используйте буферизацию вывода (`ob_start()` и `ob_get_clean()` вам в помощь)